# how to make a nested list with three types of lists in python?

Tags: python, list, nested

I have three lists:

```
EX_Num = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
Height_str = ['tall', 'medium', 'short']
total_carbon = [8.425169446611104, 8.917085904771866, 6.174348482965436]
```

How do I make a nested list where `column1 = EX_Num`, `column2 = Height_str` and `column3 = total_carbon`?

Comment: In what language? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This question is unclear, but if you are indeed using python, the semi-colons are unnecessary and shouldn't be used. I am assuming the period at the end of list 3 is a type-o but it would be a syntax error if not.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are asking... but if you just want a list of lists, just append them.

```
>>> nested_list.append(EX_Num)
>>> nested_list.append(Height_str)
>>> nested_list.append(total_carbon)
>>> nested_list
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], ['tall', 'medium', 'short'], [8.425169446611104, 8.917085904771866, 6.174348482965436]]
```

If you want all the values put into one list, just concatenate them.

```
>>> nested_list = EX_Num + Height_str + total_carbon
>>> nested_list
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 'tall', 'medium', 'short', 8.425169446611104, 8.917085904771866, 6.174348482965436]
```

If you need something different, you need to make your question more clear.]

EDIT based on comment:

If you know that all the lists are the same length:

```
nested_list = []
# be careful, if the lists aren't all the same length, you will get errors
for x in range(len(EX_Num)):
    tmp = [EX_Num[x], Height_str[x], total_carbon[x]]
    nested_list.append(tmp)
```

Comment: @ jdLemon, thanks for answering.Sorry I didn't make my question clear enough. I want to make a final list like this: [[1.0, 'tall', 8.425169446611104,], [2.0, 'medium', 8.917085904771866], [3.0, 'short', 6.174348482965436]].

Comment: I've edited my answer. You should edit your question to reflect the answer you are looking for like you posted in the comment.

Comment: @jdfLemon don't use `for` loops to pair stuff up; `zip` does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to join multiple iterables together into tuples:

```
ex = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
height = ['tall', 'medium', 'short']
total_carbon = [8.4, 8.9, 6.1]

joint = zip(ex, height, total_carbon)
print(joint)

# [(1.0, 'tall', 8.4), (2.0, 'medium', 8.9), (3.0, 'short', 6.1)]
```

Note: please don't use "hungarian notation" for your variable names (`_num`, `_str`, etc.) -- they're just clutter, *specially* in a dynamic language like Python.

---

If you need to keep related data grouped together, it's more readable to create a simple container type for it. [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) is great for this:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Thing = namedtuple('Thing', ['ex', 'height', 'total_carbon'])
my_things = [Thing(*t) for t in zip(ex, height, total_carbon)]
```

Now you can refer to stuff by name -- for example, `my_things[0].height` -- instead of needing to remember the index positions of each attribute.